# How does this Boolean simplification work?

Tags: boolean-algebra

The following expression:

$$ABC + BCD + A'D$$

simplifies to:

$$ABC + A'D$$

I just cannot understand how this comes about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Treat $BC=X$ as a single variable. Then:
$$
AX + XD + A'D = AX + (A+A')XD +A'D = AX + AXD + A'XD + A'D \\
= AX(1+D) + A'D(1+X) = AX + A'D
$$

Please tell if you did not understand anything.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Using a Karnaugh Map will make this a lot easier to understand. If you input your original statement into a 4x4 map, you end up with the following expression:

$$A'C'D + A'CD + ABC$$

simplifies to:

$$A'D + ABC$$

Here is the Wikipedia article on Karnaugh Maps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map.

Edit: The Karnaugh Map actually outputs the fully-simplified expression ABC + A'D, I just wanted to show where in the process the BCD term disappeared.

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned it in the post, but I wanted to do this via Boolean Algebra. Thank you for taking the time to answer though.

Comment: Not a problem, I hope it at least provided some insight!

Answer (score 1):

$ABC + BCD + A'D = ABC + ABCD + A'BCD + A'D = ABC + A'D$